# Scheduled function in maven dependency not running

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-scheduled

I've got a scheduled function that should run every ten seconds as per:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "*/10 * * * * *")
```

and it is included in other projects through a dependency in the Maven pom file. For whatever reason it never runs. Do I need to include anything to make this work? I've included:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
```

above the class declaration of the scheduled function.

Comment: Try adding @ComponentScan(basePackages="dep.package.tasks"), where dep.package.tasks must be the package where Spring can find the classes annotated with @Scheduled

Comment: Where would I be adding the component scan? In the main of the project that is pulling in the dependency?

Comment: In the same class you have @EnableScheduling (considering that this class is in the main project)

Comment: I tried adding that, but the scheduled task still never initiates. If I rewrite the function inside the main project and not import it as a dependency it works. It only doesn't work when I import it as a dependency.

Comment: Ok, perfect that worked! if you want to add the componentScan thing as an answer I'll checkmark it for you!:D

Comment: Good that it worked! Adding the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Boot will only auto scan the components in your project, to scan components in dependencies, add a @ComponentScan. In your case:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="dep.package")
@EnableScheduling
```

Where *dep.package* must be the package where Spring can find the classes annotated with @Scheduled.

Answer (score 0):

change version of dependency or use below dependency :-

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
     <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

and update maven project, and clean project and again build the project.

Comment: That seemed to have helped, but now I get the following error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListener : org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener